# Back navigation is broken with nested routes in a lazy-loaded module Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a lazy-loaded module which is loading another lazy-loaded module. In this module, I have nested routes. So when the user goes to the component in this module nested routes and activated but then there is no way to navigate back on click on browser's back button

I have figured out that after clicking on browser's back button it redirects to '' route in a nested routes and then goes to 'nested_route_1'.However, the logical behavior will be settings/lazy-module/nested_route_1 -> settings

```
const routes: Routes | any = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: 'nested_route_1', component: Component1 },
    { path: 'nested_route_2', component: Component2 },
    { path: 'nested_route_2', component: Component3 },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'nested_route_1'},
  ] }
];
```

Code above is my routes in this lazy-loaded module. This module is loaded from settings module. After it is loaded the nested_route_1 is activated and the url is settings/lazy-module/nested_route_1,from this moment it is impossible to navigate back to settings. How to make it possible?`enter code here`

Comment: if i understand you want to control back and forward buttons of the browser, if it is i think this article can help https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3533-using-router-events-to-detect-back-and-forward-browser-navigation-in-angular-7-0-4.htm

Comment: @JesusCarrasco is there a way to differ browser's 'back' button clicks from browser's 'front' btn clicks?